# Windows 11 notifications displayed but not moved to notification center

Tags: windows-11, notifications

I noticed that with the latest update of Win11 some apps are able to display notifications but these notifications are not moved to notification center anymore.

This means that if you are able to read the notification because you are in front of the monitor, it's ok, if you are not in front of the monitor or you are reading something else, you'll loose the notification content.

How can I tell windows to put all the notifications send from my app to notification center in order to be able to view the notification in a different moment?

All notifications should be moved to notification center to be able to see that in a different moment.

Comment: Windows  11 latest and Windows 11 Insider (future) all up to date are both working properly.  Did the interface to your App change?